# How to make sure line.new starts at closing price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm working on this indicator where i will be able to move a horizontal line as a stop loss reference. Everything is working as expected, however I have the default input value at 100. Therefore whenever I open a chart that is way above or below the price I need to search for the line or edit in settings, I wish it could just pop up at the closing price so I can easily drag it from there. I tried using defval=close, but does not work. Advice?

```
// CUSTOM LINE
tst(x)=> str.tostring(x)
var int dec = str.length(str.tostring(syminfo.mintick))-2
trc(number) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, dec)
    int(number * factor) / factor
trc_(number) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, 0)
    int(number * factor) / factor

sl_value = input.price(100, "Stop Loss")
line_color = sl_value > close ? color.green : sl_value < close ? color.red : color.black

sl_line = line.new(bar_index, sl_value, bar_index+10, sl_value, extend=extend.left,color=line_color)
sl_label = label.new(bar_index+10, sl_value, tst(trc(sl_value)), textcolor=line_color, color=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)

line.delete (sl_line[1])
label.delete(sl_label[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a draggable line you can use the `confirm` parameter:

```
sl_value = input.price(100, "Stop Loss", confirm = true)
```

This will prompt you to set the initial value of `sl_value` by positioning it on the chart, and then you can drag this value on the screen and `sl_line` will adjust accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do have a draggable line already but it needs to be set to a value (ie 100, 200 etc) but I want it to pop up around the closing price when I move to a new chart since the price can be far away and I have to navigate to the line.

sl_value = input.price(100, "Stop Loss")

// I want the 100 to be at close, but  then its not movable anymore.

Added to the initial comment to show more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use close + 100
for example:

```
var a = close + 100
sl_line = line.new(bar_index, a, bar_index+10, a, extend=extend.left,color=line_color)
```

or input.source, for example:

```
a = input.source(close, "Stop Loss")
sl_line = line.new(last_bar_index - 100, bar_index == last_bar_index?a:na, last_bar_index, a, extend=extend.left,color=color.aqua)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I do have a draggable line already (showed some more of the code In post now) but I cant make the line show up (in the first time of opening a chart) to the closing price. Now I have to navigate to find the line.

I tried it with the code above but could not make it work.